# Is there a way to change the page styles of a range of pages in Libre Office?

Tags: automation, documents, libreoffice-writer, word-processing, document-automation

I copied in pages to a target document from source documents which had page 1 (which was the page I was always cutting from) set to "First Page" style. This caused all my pages in the target document to be that style instead of the Default Style (with page number) that I wanted.

It's an easy, but very tedious fix: select the page, mash F11, 2-click "Default Style"

But I have over 300 pages to do this on. Is there a way to change the page style over a range of pages (such as 60 to 400) from one style to the other, or am I doomed to tedium?